# Is there a way to simplify this Basic Join query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm pretty new to SQL and I've been doing some exercises online to improve my query skills.

I was trying to solve this problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/contest-leaderboard/problem

I was able to solve it with the code below, but I was wondering if there's any way to simplify it/make it more efficient?

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    total_score
FROM(
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    SUM(sscore) as total_score
FROM(
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    challenge_id,
    MAX(score) as sscore
FROM(
SELECT
    hacker_id as id,
    name,
    submission_id,
    challenge_id,
    score
FROM
    Hackers
INNER JOIN
    Submissions s USING(hacker_id)
ORDER BY
    hacker_id,
    challenge_id)a
GROUP BY id, name, challenge_id)b
GROUP BY id, name
ORDER BY total_score DESC, id ASC)c
WHERE total_score > 0;
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do are all appreciated.

Comment: The link does not work. But questions should be self-contained anyway. And questions about performance are best answered by checking the execution plan and applying its recommendations or hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need a join not two or three. For controling 0 values you can use `HAVING` clause.

[image]

```
SELECT a.hacker_id,a.name, SUM(a.mscore) from (
        SELECT h.hacker_id,h.name, max(score) as mscore from Submissions s inner join hackers h on h.hacker_id=s.hacker_id group by h.hacker_id, challenge_id,h.name
    ) as a group by a.hacker_id,a.name
HAVING SUM(a.mscore) > 0
ORDER BY 3 DESC,
1 ASC
```

Comment: @user14061418 check it again please. You do not have to use same join again and again you can achieve your goal with using having clause and only one join.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I tried and it submitted successfully .

```
SELECT b.hacker_id, b.name , c.total_score from (
SELECT a.hacker_id as hid, SUM(a.max_score) as total_score from (
        SELECT hacker_id, max(score) as max_score from Submissions group by hacker_id, challenge_id
    ) as a group by a.hacker_id
) as c INNER JOIN Hackers b
ON b.hacker_id = c.hid
WHERE c.total_score > 0
ORDER BY c.total_score DESC,
b.hacker_id ASC
```